# Use Application Load Balancers | Helm chart | AWS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have deployed an application on AWS using EKS. I roughly need 20-25 loadbalancers in my application.

Now, AWS offers 20 Classic load balancers and 50 Application load balancers in my account.

I use helm chart for creating these load balancers using service => type => LoadBalancer, and these loadbalancers are considered Classic load balancers.

Is there a way to use ALB in place of CLB (either using AWS settings OR passing an option in the helm chart) ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [AWS ELB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html), You can use following ingress annotation for ingress object:

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
```

From AWS docs:

> The AWS Load Balancer Controller creates ALBs and the necessary
> supporting AWS resources whenever a Kubernetes Ingress resource is
> created on the cluster with the kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
> annotation. The Ingress resource configures the ALB to route HTTP or
> HTTPS traffic to different pods within the cluster. To ensure that
> your Ingress objects use the AWS Load Balancer Controller, add the
> following annotation to your Kubernetes Ingress specification. For
> more information, see [Ingress specification on GitHub](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/guide/ingress/spec/).

What's good in this solution is that an ALB can also be shared across multiple Ingresses, so you wouldn't need to use so many of separete LBs.

EDIT:
As mentioned by Bastian, You need to have [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) deployed to your cluster in order for it to work.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the AWS Load Balancer Controller needs to be deployed to the Cluster (see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html)) and that an additional Ingress manifest needs to be added to the Helm charts.